# How to spread Y Axis values in "area" chart using HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I have the following "area" chart, notice how the Y Axis values are not close enough which results in a very straight looking line.

```js
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  chart: { type: "area" },
  xAxis: { type: "datetime" },
  series: [
    {
      data: [
        { x: 1648959780000, y: 46245.62 },
        { x: 1648959840000, y: 46245.21 },
        { x: 1648959900000, y: 46237.67 },
        { x: 1648959960000, y: 46243.24 },
        { x: 1648960020000, y: 46252.89 },
        { x: 1648960080000, y: 46255.98 },
        { x: 1648960140000, y: 46253.31 },
        { x: 1648960200000, y: 46257.69 },
        { x: 1648960260000, y: 46254.07 },
        { x: 1648960320000, y: 46268.57 },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Whereas if I change the `type` of `chart` to `line`, the Y Axis values are nicely spread. How can I achieve a similar result using the "area" chart?

```js
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  chart: { type: "line" },
  xAxis: { type: "datetime" },
  series: [
    {
      data: [
        { x: 1648959780000, y: 46245.62 },
        { x: 1648959840000, y: 46245.21 },
        { x: 1648959900000, y: 46237.67 },
        { x: 1648959960000, y: 46243.24 },
        { x: 1648960020000, y: 46252.89 },
        { x: 1648960080000, y: 46255.98 },
        { x: 1648960140000, y: 46253.31 },
        { x: 1648960200000, y: 46257.69 },
        { x: 1648960260000, y: 46254.07 },
        { x: 1648960320000, y: 46268.57 },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The area series uses the `threshold` which a default value is 0. You need to change this value to achieve the output that you want.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wosxmc83/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.threshold